# Pygame only display picture if certain condition is met

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame and I want a picture to appear, only if the cursor is on it. Here is what I did:

```
while True:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        
        darktower_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, DARK_TOWER.get_width(), DARK_TOWER.get_height())
        if darktower_rect.collidepoint((mx,my)):
            WIN.blit(DARK_TOWERT, (x, y))
            if click:
                main()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button==1:
                    click=True
        
        pygame.display.update()
```

This works, but the problem is, that `blit` keeps the picture there, and I want the picture to disappear, after the mouse is no longer on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you blit (draw) to the `WIN` surface it will stay there until something is drawn over it, or the surface is cleared.

To clear the display after updating append to your code right after `pygame.display.update()`

`WIN.fill(0)`

This will fill the window surface with a color, if you specify `0` instead of an rgb value, the display will fill with black.

Comment: but that deletes the whole thing, i only want that 1 picture to disappear

Comment: Then there are 2 solutions: clear the frame and redraw the entire frame without the picture or redraw the section where the image was showing.

Comment: That seems like a bit overkill. Maybe i should just run a simple sprite when mouse collides with the rect

Comment: You can only draw (modify pixels) to a surface. Another solution could be to store a copy of the window surface without the image, but that's a bit overkill.